# Question regarding generating consistent dates inside of a Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase provides the following 2 methods that i know of, for working with dates when writing documents to a Firestore collection:

The following will generate a current timestamp, i assume which represents a consistent date across all regions, in the format noted in their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) and is the recommended way to get a current date at the time a document is written to a collection:

```
admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

There is also the following method which will accept a date as an argument. This will generate a result that matches that same Firestore timestamp format:

```
admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
```

I have been considering using the latter in my particular case as a means of generating a date that i can use for writing a matching date to both a document in a collection in Firestore as well as an additional separate insert into my Realtime database. I need a guarantee that the exact same date is written to both places.

What i am doing in my cloud function:

```
const datePosted = new Date();
// then when setting the data in Firestore i do the following to convert it
admin.firestore().collection(`/posts`).doc().set({
  foo: 'bar',
  datePosted: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(datePosted)
})
// followed by a subsequent write to my Realtime database using the same date
admin.database().ref(`posts`).set({
  foo: 'bar',
  datePosted: Date.parse(datePosted)
})
```

Can anyone offer any insight into whether or not this approach is a bad idea? I need to find out whether or not generating a date in the way i described is a valid approach or if it is unreliable in the sense that the dates generated in my documents could vary depending on when and/or what region the instance of my cloud function is instantiated. *I am eluding to the varying time it could take for a cloud function to instantiate across different regions or for any other reason for that matter.*

Comment: If you really want to have the exact same Timestamp value ("I need a guarantee that the exact same date is written to both places"), you could first write to Firestore (using serverTimestamp), read the document to get the value and use this value to write to the RTDB. Of course this implies an extra read...

Comment: Yeah, thank you for taking the time to respond. I was hoping to avoid that, not to mention the latency involved as well .. but i am accessing the date via an onCreate listener method for the time being and looking to refactor all together to avoid needed the date in 2 places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` generates a timestamp which is guaranteed to be accurate, as reckoned by Google.  The actual time will be resolved when the request hits Firestore, even if the request gets delayed for some reason (such as being offline).

`admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())` generates a timestamp which uses the current time as reckoned by the users device.  **There is no guarantee that the user's device has an accurate time set. Use this only if you want to know the clock time on the user's device, even if it's inaccurate.**

It's up to you.  If you want a guaranteed accurate time at the time the request hits the server, use the server timestamp.  If you want the client's reckoning of time, use `new Date()`.

Comment: Thank you. The top priority for me is a matching date in Firestore and the Realtime Database, so i can accept if the time is off by a few seconds, but the timestamps need to match in both documents. When you say the 'client's reckoning of time' ... i am generating a date in a cloud function, not on the client ... my concern was whether or not different regions could vary greatly as a result.

Comment: Region doesn't matter at all, since Timestamps don't have a timezone encoded in them.  They just encode the number of seconds and milliseconds since the unix epoch, which is the same around the world.

Comment: Understood... i am not articulating myself clearly here though. By region i am eluding to start up performance for cloud functions. To put it plainly ... say a user triggers the cloud function which happens to start up quickly and generate a write at one point in time ... when another user had triggered an entirely separate instance of that cloud function say 6 seconds earlier which was delayed in starting for roughly 6 seconds... i would assume the latent write would post to the database with the most recent date in that case.

Comment: The timestamp will be generated at the moment that `new Date()` line of code is executed. It's not based on when the function was triggered.  So, if it takes 6 seconds from the start of the function to get to that line of code, it will see a delay of 6 seconds from that time.  IMO, in practice, unless you know a very specific time you want to put in the field, it's better to take the server time.  There is no hard guarantee that timestamp will be unique.  I would say it's likely to be unique, but not guaranteed.